# Unautorized API calls JwtCreator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docusignapi

I'm playing around with the DocuSign's Ruby Quickstart app and I've done the following:

- have an Admin account
- have an organization
- created an Integration(Connected App) for which I've granted  signature impersonation scopes in the Admin Dashboard(made RSA keys, put callback urls, etc)
- even if I've done the above, I've also made the request to the consent URL in a browser: SERVER/oauth/auth?response_type=code &scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=CLIENT_ID &redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
- Integration appears to have everything enabled

Then in the JwtCreator class the `check_jwt_token` returns true, updates account info correctly.

But when I try the following(or any other API call):

```
 envelope_api = create_envelope_api(@args)
 options = DocuSign_eSign::ListStatusChangesOptions.new
 options.from_date = (Date.today - 30).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
 
 results = envelope_api.list_status_changes @args[:account_id], options
```

The api call raises an exception with `DocuSign_eSign::ApiError (Unauthorized):`

Args are:

```
@args = {
      account_id: session[:ds_account_id],
      base_path: session[:ds_base_path],
      access_token: session[:ds_access_token]
     }
```

All with correct info.

What am I missing?

Comment: This `api_client = DocuSign_eSign::ApiClient.new configuration` has the correct URLs(host: demo.docusign.net and base_path: /restapi)

Comment: Made another connected app and took it step by step: grating it access via scopes in the Admin section made no difference, couldn't get JWT, constructing the URL and manually giving consent worked, got token but any subsequent API call results in the same 'Unauthorized'.

Comment: Also adding the fact that the call for user info works: `effective_url=https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo response_code=200 return_code=ok total_time=0.387427`

Comment: you mentioned you are using the Quickstart, yet you're saying you creating the keys yourself? I'm confused about what exactly you are doing. Are you going via this page - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/ and getting a ZIP file downloaded?

Comment: Using some of the Quickstart classes(like JWT creator) along with some custom code. Initially I downloaded the zip and everything was fine but then I needed something custom and created a new project and new integration app but with some of the classes from quickstart. The keys were made on docusign under integration&keys. Since yesterday I made it work by including the Account ID with the bearer token. Not sure if it's the correct way or not, but it works.

Comment: So in the Quickstart example, for api calls it was using account guid, in the medium tutorial I've found, it sent the 1xxxxxx account id and with this, it works.

Comment: my guess is that the GUID you had for account_id was for a different account or was incorrect for some other reason. You should be able to use either the GUID or the short version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity, I was using some classes from the Quickstart app(like JwtCreator, ApiCreator, etc) along my code.
Not sure at this point if it's my mistake or part of the Quickstart app but this call:

```
results = envelope_api.list_status_changes @args[:account_id], options
```

the `account_id` was something like this `"82xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx95e"` and I was always getting Unauthorized responses.
On a medium.com tutorial the author used the `1xxxxxx` `account_id` and with this form, it worked.

Comment: both short and long (GUID) account_id should work, but perhaps you had the wrong long one...

Comment: It's possible, thank you for the answers @InbarGazit